# How to split up ipv6 and ipv4 from one string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a library that passes me a string for the users ip address that looks like this- "::ffff:10.10.102.86"

I don't want to change the code in that library for many reasons. Obviously the leftmost side is ipv6 and the rightmost side is v4.

What is the best way to split this up into two strings for v6 and v4?

I've tried some other regex matches but these did not work:

```
var ipv6 = ip.match(/^(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:){7}(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|:)|(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:){6}(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}|:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|:)|(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:){5}(?::(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}|(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){1,2}|:)|(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:){4}(?:(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){0,1}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}|(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){1,3}|:)|(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:){3}(?:(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){0,2}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}|(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){1,4}|:)|(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:){2}(?:(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){0,3}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}|(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){1,5}|:)|(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:){1}(?:(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){0,4}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}|(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){1,6}|:)|(?::(?:(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){0,5}:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}|(?::[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}){1,7}|:)))(?:%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})?$/gm);

var ipv4 = ip.match(/^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}$/gm);
```

Appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: This is an [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=addresses-ipv4-mapped-ipv6)

Comment: Thanks, that sheds a bit more light on why it's formatted this way. Do you see any issue with splitting them up as described below?

Comment: The full thing ___is___ the IPv6 address, [::ffff] is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do it like this instead of creating very complicated regEx expressions.

```
const arr = "::ffff:10.10.102.86".split(':')
const ipV4 = arr.pop()
const ipV6 = arr.join(':')
```

Comment: Wow, that was a lot simpler solution than I thought :) Log output shows CLIENT IP V4: [10.10.102.86] V6: [::ffff] when i print out each var, thanks!!

Comment: The original value ___is___ the IPv6 address - `::ffff` is not correct.